# Does Renovatebot run composer plugins?

Tags: composer-php, renovate

I'm trying to find out if Composer plugins work with Renovatebot, because, in my local environment, the lines below *merge* the `webform/composer.libraries.json` with my `composer.json`, but do not work with the GitHub/Renovate integration.

It is like the merge plugin is not running when Renovatebot does the updates.

```
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "docroot/modules/contrib/webform/composer.libraries.json"
            ]
        }
```

Regarding the "GitHub/Renovate integration": when you add a `renovate.json` file and your repo is in GitHub, Renovate will update your packages (composer, npm, etc) and create the PRs. That is what I mean by "Github/Renovate" integration. The error I'm facing, is that when Renovate updates the lock, is not merging/considering the packages from "docroot/modules/contrib/webform/composer.libraries.json"

Comment: "this works in my local, but not using the Github/Renovate integration" - what happens instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase: the webform libraries in `composer.libraries.json` are _merged_ into the `composer.json` and included when generating the lock file. Locally, works. I don't have to copy/paste those libraries into my composer.json file.

Comment: "do not work with the GitHub/Renovate integration" what does that mean? Are you facing any error message?

Comment: If you add a renovate.json file and your repo is in GitHub, Renovate will update your packages (composer, npm, etc) and create PRs. That is what I mean by "Github/Renovate" integration.
The error I'm facing, is that when Renovate updates the lock, is not merging/considering the packages from "docroot/modules/contrib/webform/composer.libraries.json". Thanks!

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

> Does Renovatebot run composer plugins?

No, at least not in the default configuration, and as they have not shared the configuration of their Renovatebot setup, we can only answer the question for that default configuration.

However, the answer is also:

Yes, at least in a specific self-hosted configuration by default. But then they would not have asked the question.

As it remains a bit vague what the issue is with finding it out ([the Renovatebot has documentation](https://docs.renovatebot.com/)), it may help to ask the question first how Renovatebot could learn about the Composer plugins in use.

As those are in the localhost configuration only, it can't. There is no configuration setting for Renovatebot to tell about Composer plugins to use.

Even we for ourselves could not say from the `composer.json` excerpt shared in their question, as there is no public registry for those settings in `composer.json`, so this requires individual research per each entry. Something that does not make sense for a bot running automated.

However, if they ask the question because they *want* this to be, then they should take care of applying all changes to `composer.json` within the automation **prior** the run of Renovatebot (as it only looks into the ***requires*** in `composer.json` and equivalents in `composer.lock`, cf. [Renovate PHP Language Support](https://docs.renovatebot.com/php/) ).

**Creating a merge request may not make sense afterwards.**

However, as it is possible to tell Renovatebot about the files to scan, it *may* be an option to apply the update also to the source of `composer.libraries.json` if it is in a supported format.

---

Mix and match for their standard scenario, then maintain their solution. As long as Renovatebot uses the `composer` command [from `PATH`](https://docs.renovatebot.com/self-hosted-configuration/#binarysource), they have all plugins of that binaries' configuration (mind [`COMPOSER_HOME`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home)).

So technically, in a non-default configuration (or in a specific self-hosted configuration by default), the answer is yes, not no. But if it helps is a different question. Perhaps for end-users that are not interested in merge-requests to push upstream.